# ¿Cómo hacer un super de una función que está en otro fichero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-3.7

Tengo 2 ficheros y quiero importar esta función que tengo en este fichero *carga.py*

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
   def rango_fecha((self, anio: Optional[int], empieza: Optional[str], end: Optional[str]) -> Tuple[date, date]:):
      print("lo que sea")
```

Y usarla aquí:
fichero2.py

```
from foro.management.commands.carga import Command as FechaCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
   def rango_fecha(self, anio: Optional[int], empieza: Optional[str], end: Optional[str]) -> Tuple[
    date, date]:
       return super(FechaCommand, self).rango_fecha(anio, empieza, end)

   def handle(self, *args, anio: Optional[int]=None, empieza: Optional[str]=None, end: Optional[str]=None, **options):
       fecha_fin = self.rango_fecha(anio, empieza, end)
```

¿Cómo tendría que hacer el super correctamente?

Mensaje de error:

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Comment: Ya te han respondido que no puedes usar `super()` si no hay herencia. Dices que falla `FechaCommand().rango_fecha(anio, empieza, end)` que sería lo adecuado. Completa tu pregunta y tu código para que podamos darte alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo. También estaría bien que explicaras qué resultados pretendes conseguir.

Answer (score 0):

Con **super** se suele llamar a las clases padres, como es el caso de la que estás heredando (BaseCommand). En este caso, la clase que importas no es hereditaria, por tanto no puedes hacer eso.
Si realmente necesitas llamar a la función de esa clase externa, o creas una instancia suya, o haces que la función **rango_fecha** sea estática, y la llamas con

```
`FechaCommand.rango_fecha(anio, empieza, end)`
```

Edit:

```
class A():
    def prueba(self):
        print("a") 
class B(A):     
    @classmethod     
    def prueba2(self):         
        print("b") 
class C(A):     
    def prueba2(self):         
        B.prueba2()  

c = C() 
c.prueba2()    ----> "b"
```

Comment: eso tampoco se puede hacer es lo primero que probé antes de probar hacer el super.
Al hacer lo así no me hace nada, luego probé así FechaCommand().rango_fecha(anio, empieza, end) 
que así da un error

Comment: Me resulta raro que no funcione por estática. Te edito la respuesta con un ejemplo muy sencillo y me comentas si es lo mismo que estas probando.